# How do you enter binary numbers in OS X Calculator?

Tags: macos

I'm using Calculator on Mac OS X 10.7.5.  I switched it to the "Programmer" view, and the upper right only has "8", "10", and "16" buttons, which means it only allows you to enter octal, decimal, and hexadecimal numbers.  How can I enter binary numbers?

[image]

Comment: If your dead pressed on using apples native calculator its not that easy. There are better web alternatives or even use terminal if you feel like it. But theres only so much you can do with that calculator.

Comment: There is a better calculator for dealing with bits: https://bitcalc.abeghyan.com/

Answer (score 13):

Click "show binary" button, this shows in your screenshot, and then you can click the "bit" you want to set.

Comment: Thanks, that is a really bizarre way of doing it (what the heck was Apple thinking?).  You also can't paste a binary number into Calculator that way, so I wonder if there's an easier way to enter binary numbers.

Comment: Haha, 2021 outside and still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little trick to entering and doing binary math on the built in Calc App and that's to put it into [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) mode via  <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

Then, add the binary digits to the stack by clicking on each bit then performing your operations.  Below is a very basic calculation showing how you can enter binary numbers (Sorry for the large size, needed to show the bit selection)

[image]

(IMO) This isn't the easiest calculator to utilize, but this will do in a pinch.